# Cordova geolocation plugin causes build error

Tags: cordova, geolocation, cordova-plugins

I have a cordova application with two platforms enabled, ios and android. I am attempting to use the geolocation plugin, but I get an error message during builds. Running "cordova build ios" or "cordova build android" produces the following output at the start of the build:

```
Discovered plugin "Geolocation" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Failed to restore plugin "Geolocation" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/Geolocation
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'Geolocation' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 Your package name is not valid, because 
npm ERR! 404  1. name can no longer contain capital letters
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ahnilica/.npm/_logs/2018-01-29T22_15_59_955Z-debug.log
.
.
.
.
```

The build succeeds, but geolocation services do not work in the app. I have tried removing and re-adding the plugin, but the result is the same.

Global Config.xml:

```
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^4.0.1" />
    <engine name="android" spec="^6.3.0" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="^4.5.3" />
```

Android Config.xml:

```
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Whitelist">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.whitelist.WhitelistPlugin" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.Geolocation" />
    </feature>
```

iOS Config.xml:

```
    <feature name="LocalStorage">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocalStorage" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Console">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLogger" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="HandleOpenUrl">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVHandleOpenURL" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="IntentAndNavigationFilter">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVIntentAndNavigationFilter" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="GestureHandler">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVGestureHandler" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
    </feature>
```

Cordova Version: 8.0.0
NPM Version: 5.6.0

Comment: Please be more specific about your issue

Comment: What additional information should I provide?